# Why are all solution files checked for commit when get solution from subversion

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

When I get solution from subversion server, all my files are checked by default in Pending changes pane.

How to escape this without committing all files? And why is this happening?

Comment: Show us the screenshot. After you **GET** solution from Subversion, your working copy is not modified, thus the Pending Changes windows should be blank. Do you checkout to empty / new directory? Or do you **ADD* solution to Subversion?

Comment: I know that Pending changes windows should be blank, but it isn't. I am going from Visual Studio 2012 to `VISUAL SVN` option in menu, and choose `Get Solution from Subversion` and choose new folder that not exist on file system. So, everything from zero. And my solution is here in Visual Studio, but showing that is completely changed, and wait for commit

Comment: Hmm. In Pending Changes, right-click any modified item and select "Show Differences". What's changed in the file? It could be some issue with line endings, or another app modifies these files right after you complete the checkout.

Comment: I think that problem was in that my project has root folder MyProject, and when I get solution from subversion, I create another folder with same name, and nested solution MyProject into another MyProject folder, so hierarchy was harmed.